# Display form result on same page using php with smarty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, smarty

My web app is integrated to facebook. I created a form in tpl file with only has one input, which is select input. User has to choose one of his facebook group. The `value` of the option is `id` of each group.

So this is what i would like to do :

When user change the option (`onchange`), list of members of the selected group will appear bellow the `select` `div`. I don't know what i should use (javascript, jquery, ajax, etc) and how to implement it in my code.

Here my code snippet :

```
 {* --- form in tpl file --- *}
   <form method="post">
    <fieldset>
     <div class="row">
         <p style="font-weight:bold;">Choose your facebook group :</p>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
         <select name="group" onchange="idontknow">
             {foreach from=$userGroupsData item=group}
                <option value="{$group.id}">{$group.name}</option>
             {/foreach}
         </select>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
             {* the place where members list will appear *}
     </div>
    </fieldset>
   </form>
```

PHP code to retrieve member list of selected group (if I use submit method) :

```
<?php
$groupId = $_POST['group'];
$groupmember = $facebook->api('/'.$groupId.'/members');
$membergroup = $groupmember['data'];

foreach ($membergroup as $membergroups) {
    echo "<li>".$membergroups['name']."</li>";      
}
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make an Ajax request using jQuery:

```
$(function() {

    $('body').on('change', 'select[name="group"]', function() {

        var groupId = $(this).val();

        $.post('path/to/your/script', groupId)
            .done(function(data) {
                $('form .row').html(data);
            });
    });

});
```

If it were me, I would have the backend return JSON data instead of HTML and I would build the HTML dynamically in the Ajax callback.

Also, this scenario is one of the many reasons I prefer to use MVC architecture on the backend. If you were using an MVC framework like say CodeIgniter for example, the URL you're posting the data to would take care of the routing like this:

**MVC-style URL** = 'mycontroller/mymethod/myparam'.

In this example, mycontroller would be the class (script) you're calling, mymethod would be the specific function you want to call in the controller, and myparam would be the data you're passing to that function.